# Best way to have a component displaying data that has been looped through in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

I have a component that displays a grid of elements. These elements are all composed by the same thing except that each element has a different city and price.

This city and price I am grabbing from a data.js file I got.

At the moment this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {countries} from "../database/data"
import { FaMapMarkerAlt,FaPlaneDeparture } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { BsArrowDownShort } from 'react-icons/bs';

class CitiesExplained extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {countries}
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="pt-20 pl-6">
               {countries.map((country, index) => (
             <div className="grid grid-cols-2" key={index}>
                 <div className="bg-top bg-cover bg-no-repeat h-2/5 w-5/6 rounded-t-lg " style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${country.cities['id-2'].src})` }}
                 >
                       <div className="  ml-1 mt-2 pl-1 pr-1 flex flex-row justify-between">
                     <div className=" bg-white rounded-full p-2 text-blue-500">
                     <FaPlaneDeparture/>
                     </div>
                     <p>
                         <span className=" text-white opacity-90 pr-1"> From</span>
                        <span className="text-white font-bold" >{country.cities['id-1'].price}</span>
                     </p>
                     </div>
                <div className="mt-10">
                        <div className="bg-white border-1 shadow-md border-gray-300 flex flex-col pb-6 rounded-b-lg">
                            <div className="flex flex-row">
                                <BsArrowDownShort  color="orange" size="25px"/>
                                <p className="pl-2 text-blue-500 font-bold ">{country.countryCapital}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className=" flex flex-row" > 
                                <FaMapMarkerAlt color="rgb(75,85,99)"/>
                                <p className=" pl-2 text-gray-600 font-bold ">{country.cities['id-1'].name}</p>     
                            </div>                   
                </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="bg-top bg-cover bg-no-repeat h-2/5 w-5/6 rounded-t-lg " style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${country.cities['id-2'].src})` }}
                 >
                     <div className="  ml-1 mt-2 pl-1 pr-1 flex flex-row justify-between">
                     <div className=" bg-white rounded-full p-2 text-blue-500">
                     <FaPlaneDeparture/>
                     </div>
                     <p>
                         <span className=" text-white opacity-90 pr-1"> From</span>
                        <span className="text-white font-bold" >{country.cities['id-1'].price}</span>
                     </p>
                     </div>
                <div className="mt-10">
                        <div className="bg-white flex flex-col pb-6 rounded-b-lg shadow-md border-gray-300 ">
                            <div className="flex flex-row">
                                <BsArrowDownShort  color="orange" size="25px"/>
                                <p className="pl-2 text-blue-500 font-bold ">{country.countryCapital}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className=" flex flex-row" > 
                                <FaMapMarkerAlt color="rgb(75,85,99)"/>
                                <p className=" pl-2 text-gray-600 font-bold ">{country.cities['id-2'].name}</p>     
                            </div>                   
                </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="bg-top bg-cover bg-no-repeat h-2/5 w-5/6 rounded-t-lg " style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${country.cities['id-2'].src})` }}
                 >
                     <div className="  ml-1 mt-2 pl-1 pr-1 flex flex-row justify-between">
                     <div className=" bg-white rounded-full p-2 text-blue-500">
                     <FaPlaneDeparture/>
                     </div>
                     <p>
                         <span className=" text-white opacity-90 pr-1"> From</span>
                        <span className="text-white font-bold" >{country.cities['id-1'].price}</span>
                     </p>
                     </div>
                <div className="mt-10">
                        <div className="bg-white flex flex-col pb-6 rounded-b-lg shadow-md border-gray-300 ">
                            <div className="flex flex-row">
                                <BsArrowDownShort  color="orange" size="25px"/>
                                <p className="pl-2 text-blue-500 font-bold ">{country.countryCapital}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className=" flex flex-row" > 
                                <FaMapMarkerAlt color="rgb(75,85,99)"/>
                                <p className=" pl-2 text-gray-600 font-bold ">{country.cities['id-2'].name}</p>     
                            </div>                   
                </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="bg-top bg-cover bg-no-repeat h-2/5 w-5/6 rounded-t-lg " style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${country.cities['id-2'].src})` }}
                 >
                     <div className="  ml-1 mt-2 pl-1 pr-1 flex flex-row justify-between">
                     <div className=" bg-white rounded-full p-2 text-blue-500">
                     <FaPlaneDeparture/>
                     </div>
                     <p>
                         <span className=" text-white opacity-90 pr-1"> From</span>
                        <span className="text-white font-bold" >{country.cities['id-1'].price}</span>
                     </p>
                     </div>
                <div className="mt-10">
                        <div className="bg-white flex flex-col pb-6 rounded-b-lg shadow-md border-gray-300 ">
                            <div className="flex flex-row">
                                <BsArrowDownShort  color="orange" size="25px"/>
                                <p className="pl-2 text-blue-500 font-bold ">{country.countryCapital}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className=" flex flex-row" > 
                                <FaMapMarkerAlt color="rgb(75,85,99)"/>
                                <p className=" pl-2 text-gray-600 font-bold ">{country.cities['id-2'].name}</p>     
                            </div>                   
                </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="bg-top bg-cover bg-no-repeat h-2/5 w-5/6 rounded-t-lg " style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${country.cities['id-2'].src})` }}
                 >
                     <div className="  ml-1 mt-2 pl-1 pr-1 flex flex-row justify-between">
                     <div className=" bg-white rounded-full p-2 text-blue-500">
                     <FaPlaneDeparture/>
                     </div>
                     <p>
                         <span className=" text-white opacity-90 pr-1"> From</span>
                        <span className="text-white font-bold" >{country.cities['id-1'].price}</span>
                     </p>
                     </div>
                <div className="mt-10">
                        <div className="bg-white flex flex-col pb-6 rounded-b-lg shadow-md border-gray-300 ">
                            <div className="flex flex-row">
                                <BsArrowDownShort  color="orange" size="25px"/>
                                <p className="pl-2 text-blue-500 font-bold ">{country.countryCapital}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className=" flex flex-row" > 
                                <FaMapMarkerAlt color="rgb(75,85,99)"/>
                                <p className=" pl-2 text-gray-600 font-bold ">{country.cities['id-2'].name}</p>     
                            </div>                   
                </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="bg-top bg-cover bg-no-repeat h-2/5 w-5/6 rounded-t-lg " style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${country.cities['id-2'].src})` }}
                 >
                     <div className="  ml-1 mt-2 pl-1 pr-1 flex flex-row justify-between">
                     <div className=" bg-white rounded-full p-2 text-blue-500">
                     <FaPlaneDeparture/>
                     </div>
                     <p>
                         <span className=" text-white opacity-90 pr-1"> From</span>
                        <span className="text-white font-bold" >{country.cities['id-1'].price}</span>
                     </p>
                     </div>
                <div className="mt-10">
                        <div className="bg-white flex flex-col pb-6 rounded-b-lg shadow-md border-gray-300 ">
                            <div className="flex flex-row">
                                <BsArrowDownShort  color="orange" size="25px"/>
                                <p className="pl-2 text-blue-500 font-bold ">{country.countryCapital}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className=" flex flex-row" > 
                                <FaMapMarkerAlt color="rgb(75,85,99)"/>
                                <p className=" pl-2 text-gray-600 font-bold ">{country.cities['id-2'].name}</p>     
                            </div>                   
                </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>    
                  
          </div>  
          
        ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CitiesExplained;
```

The idea is to have a total of a grid with 6 elements but in order to do that at the moment I have 6 divs rather than 1 div only in which the data varies depending on the length of the array.

My data file is the following:

```
export const countries = [    
    {
        "country-id": 1,    
        "countryName": "Australia",
        "countryCapital": "Sydney",
        "cities": {
            "id-1":{
            "name":"Melbourne",
            "price":"$50",
            "src": "/images/merbourne-city.jpg",
            },
            "id-2":{
                "name":"Brisbane",
                "price":"$50",
                "src": "/images/brisbane-city.jpg",
            },
            "id-3":{
                "name":"Perth",
                "src": "/images/merbourne-city.jpg",
            },
            "id-4":{
                "name":"Armidale",
                "src": "/images/merbourne-city.jpg",
                "airportShort":"ARM"
            },
            "id-5":{
                "name":"Narrandera",
                "airportShort":"NRA",
                "src": "/images/merbourne-city.jpg",
            },
            "id-6":{
                "name":"Meekathara",
                "airportShort":"MKR",
                "src": "/images/merbourne-city.jpg",
            },
        }
    }
    ]
```

What's the best way to have a cleaner and less repetitive code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to create separate div in your render method. instead just loop through the country object key field using .map function and return the single div from it and just change the name of the field dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to create a seperate component for displaying
a single city information and then use that component for displaying each city.

Answer (score 0):

Pls alter your code as follows.

CitiesExplained.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {countries} from "../database/data"
import { FaMapMarkerAlt,FaPlaneDeparture } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { BsArrowDownShort } from 'react-icons/bs';

class CitiesExplained extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {countries}
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="pt-20 pl-6">
               {countries.map((country, index) => (
             <div className="grid grid-cols-2" key={index}>
                 <CityInfo img={country.cities['id-2'].src} price={country.cities['id-1'].price} capital={country.countryCapital} name={country.cities['id-1'].name} />
          </div>  
          
        ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CitiesExplained;
```

CityInfo.js

```
import React from 'react';

const CityInfo = (props) => {

    let {img, price, capital, name} = props;

    return(
                      <div className="bg-top bg-cover bg-no-repeat h-2/5 w-5/6 rounded-t-lg " style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${img})` }}
                 >
                     <div className="  ml-1 mt-2 pl-1 pr-1 flex flex-row justify-between">
                     <div className=" bg-white rounded-full p-2 text-blue-500">
                     <FaPlaneDeparture/>
                     </div>
                     <p>
                         <span className=" text-white opacity-90 pr-1"> From</span>
                        <span className="text-white font-bold" >{price}</span>
                     </p>
                     </div>
                <div className="mt-10">
                        <div className="bg-white flex flex-col pb-6 rounded-b-lg shadow-md border-gray-300 ">
                            <div className="flex flex-row">
                                <BsArrowDownShort  color="orange" size="25px"/>
                                <p className="pl-2 text-blue-500 font-bold ">{capital}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className=" flex flex-row" > 
                                <FaMapMarkerAlt color="rgb(75,85,99)"/>
                                <p className=" pl-2 text-gray-600 font-bold ">{name}</p>     
                            </div>                   
                </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
);
}

export default CityInfo;
```